# Thank you URL is not loading outside the form iframe

Tags: javascript, html, forms, velo

I have embedded a form on my wix website - it looks like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://premier.formstack.com/forms/js.php/formname"></script>
```

But the thank you page URL keeps loading inside the form frame. How can I force it to load on the parent page upon submission?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.

Comment: I am confused. I don't see any `<iframe>` tags here, so what does the title mean? Also, I don't know what you mean with "thank you page URL", there is nothing like that visible in your code example.

Comment: This is the script for the form <script type="text/javascript" src="https://premier.formstack.com/forms/js.php/form name"></script> - the thank you page is specified in the form settings in formstack.

Comment: Dont know where this weird code came from - apologies its the first time I am using stack overflow and clearly Ive done something wrong! :)

Answer (score 0):

As fas as I see, you have embedded **JavaScript**, when I checked, it basically adds form to the document.

```
document.write("<!DOCTYPE html>"+"\n");
document.write("<html  lang=\"\">"+"\n");
document.write("<head>"+"\n");
document.write("    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />"+"\n");
document.write("    <title>Formstack</title>"+"\n");
document.write("    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/forms/style.css\" />"+"\n");
document.write("</head>"+"\n");
document.write("<body>"+"\n");
document.write("    <div id=\"error\" class=\"formError\"><strong>ERROR:</strong> It looks like we couldn\'t find a form with that URL. Please double-check the URL and try again. If you\'re still having trouble, try contacting the person who sent you this form. (Error ID: b15b76df14cf6527b8ee)"+"\n");
document.write("        "+"\n");
document.write("                <br /><br />"+"\n");
document.write("        <form class=\"formErrorBack\" action=\"\">"+"\n");
document.write("            <input type=\"button\" value=\"Back\" onclick=\"history.back()\" />"+"\n");
document.write("        </form>"+"\n");
document.write("                "+"\n");
document.write("    </div>"+"\n");
document.write("</body>"+"\n");
document.write("</html>"+"\n");
document.write(""+"\n");
```

But you need to specify the `formname`

Example when I replaced it by `30_day_employee_review` you can the see the form loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://premier.formstack.com/forms/js.php/30_day_employee_review"></script>
```

*Cheers and welcome to StackOverflow!*

Comment: Thanks Sunil B N. I used formname as an example - not in my actual code. The form itself works -and displays properly. Its the thank you page that loads in the iframe and breaks everything.

Comment: "breaks" means? does it disturb your UI? page hangs? Can you share more code to understand what exactly is happening.

Comment: By breaks I mean that it loads a new page in the iframe of the form. The problem is that wix adds the iframe which I cannot edit but I think I found a way around it. Many thanks for your help!